# Class Hierarchy problem using @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions, spring-orm

Project setup: Spring 3.0.5 / JPA 2 / Hibernate / @Transactional

We work with several different Data Sources (and hence different transaction managers), but have common Service base classes, as a lot of the functionality is reused.

So we thought we'd solve this by using [Custom Annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-custom-attributes). We define all methods in an abstract base class, and create one empty implementation class per Transaction Manager.

Now the problem is:

In [`AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource`](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.transaction/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java), this is the lookup that is being done:

```
TransactionAttribute txAtt = findTransactionAttribute(specificMethod);
// ...
// Second try is the transaction attribute on the target class.
txAtt = findTransactionAttribute(specificMethod.getDeclaringClass());
```

First the method is checked, then the class that declares the method (and its ancestors). But in our context, the custom annotation resides in a subclass that can't be found by going upwards.

So how can we solve this problem?

[I also asked this question [in the Spring Community Forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?109443-Class-Hierarchy-problem-using-Transactional)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, we solved this issue by providing

1. our own subclass of
   [`AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource`](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.transaction/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.java)
   which does a lookup on the target
   class first and then delegates to
   the super class
2. A [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors) that substitues our implementation for the original `AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource` bean definition that is created internally by `<tx:annotation-driven>`

.

Answer (score 4):

Great catch. I don't know a good solution but as a workaround, you can override the methods in question in the implementation like so:

```
@Override
void method(...)
    // Just to work around a bug in AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource
    super.method(...);
}
```

that will make the `@Transactional` visible but it's ugly :-/

Comment: I have thought of this. It is ugly, but it is also an obvious solution as a last resort. Perhaps if the individual subclasses are generated automatically, I'll think of that. +1 to you for making sense :-), but obviously this isn't what I'm looking for